# error building roboearth

Tags: ros, rosmake, roboearth, rospack, buiding-errors

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone...i manage to install roboearth but having problem during building it...below are the output after rosmake roboearth...can some body tell me what gone wrong? sorry im still new in ROS....

after doing the suggestion...now i get new error...get the broken dependecy..how to fix it...?

mkdir -p bin cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=rospack find rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake .. [rosbuild] Building package re_comm Failed to invoke /opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests re_comm [rospack] couldn't find dependency [rosjava_jni] of [re_comm] [rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 're_comm'.  Look
above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:206 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack) CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of package re_comm written to: [ rosmake ] /home/azfaryusof/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120422-003438/re_comm/build_output.log [rosmake-0] Finished <<< re_comm [FAIL] [ 0.32 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package re_comm. [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete. [ rosmake ] All 22 lines {------------------------------------------------------------------------------- mkdir -p bin cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=rospack find rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake .. [rosbuild] Building package re_2dmap_extractor Failed to invoke /opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests re_2dmap_extractor [rospack] couldn't find dependency [rosjava_jni] of [re_2dmap_extractor] [rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
're_2dmap_extractor'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:206 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack) CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} [ rosmake ] Output from build of package re_2dmap_extractor written to: [ rosmake ] /home/azfaryusof/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120422-003438/re_2dmap_extractor/build_output.log [rosmake-1] Finished <<< re_2dmap_extractor [FAIL] [ 0.30 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package re_2dmap_extractor. [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete. [ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 3 packages with 2 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/azfaryusof/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120422-003438

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32313/error-building-roboearth/) by [ay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2017/ay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2017/ay/) on 2012-04-22**:
i think i missing rosjava_jni...can anobody help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to install the ros-electric-client-rosjava-jni, if you are using the Ubuntu packages.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0